# In Google Sheets, how can I line up 2 data sets by date on a line chart?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to create a line chart with 2 lines, each using data from a separate sheet. Both sheets contain dates and values. The dates are overlapping but do not have the same beginning date.

My data looks like this:

**Sheet 1**

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2023 | 100 |
| 1/2/2023 | 100 |
| 1/3/2023 | 100 |
| 1/4/2023 | 100 |
| 1/5/2023 | 100 |
| 1/6/2023 | 100 |
| 1/7/2023 | 100 |
| 1/8/2023 | 100 |

**Sheet 2**

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1/5/2023 | 10 |
| 1/6/2023 | 15 |
| 1/7/2023 | 20 |
| 1/8/2023 | 25 |
| 1/9/2023 | 30 |

You can see that the first set of data goes from Jan 1-Jan 8, and the second set of data goes from Jan 5-Jan 9.

My data range is `'Sheet 1'!A1:B99,'Sheet 2'!A1:B99`. When I create a line chart with this data, the plotted line from **Sheet 1** - the first data set - is plotted accurately.

The problem is that the second line on the chart is not placed in proper accordance to the date. The distribution and shape of the line are correct, but it appears on the chart in the wrong position. The values start at the beginning of the chart, as if the date column from **Sheet 2** is being ignored.

For example, the first row from **Sheet 2** is `[1/5/2023, 10]`. It should be plotted halfway through the chart, but it appears at `[1/1/2023]` instead.

Is there a way that I can accurately plot this data without having to create a new third sheet which aggregates it all with a shared date column?

Answer (score 1):

No doubt there are many ways to do this, but the key is that the X-Axis values have to be contiguous.

For this answer, I used:

`=query({choosecols(Sheet1!A2:C9,1,2,3);choosecols(Sheet2!A2:C6,1,3,2)})`

The headers are entered manually.

---

**DATA**

[image: data]

---

**GRAPH**

[image: chart]